# Issue on making greenbone-security-assistant

Tags: installation, cmake, pkg-config, openvas

I tried to make greenbone to use openvas as below:

i seems openvas installed correctly. this is openvas-check-setup output:

```
Step 1: Checking OpenVAS Scanner ...
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner is present in version 5.0.5.
        OK: OpenVAS Scanner CA Certificate is present as /var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem.
        OK: redis-server is present in version v=2.8.4.
        OK: scanner (kb_location setting) is configured properly using the redis-server socket: /var/run/redis/redis.sock
        OK: redis-server is running and listening on socket: /var/run/redis/redis.sock.
        OK: redis-server configuration is OK and redis-server is running.
        OK: NVT collection in /var/lib/openvas/plugins contains 45702 NVTs.
        WARNING: Signature checking of NVTs is not enabled in OpenVAS Scanner.
        SUGGEST: Enable signature checking (see http://www.openvas.org/trusted-nvts.html).
        OK: The NVT cache in /var/cache/openvas contains 45702 files for 45702 NVTs.
Step 2: Checking OpenVAS Manager ...
        OK: OpenVAS Manager is present in version 6.0.7.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager client certificate is present as /var/lib/openvas/CA/clientcert.pem.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database found in /var/lib/openvas/mgr/tasks.db.
        OK: Access rights for the OpenVAS Manager database are correct.
        OK: sqlite3 found, extended checks of the OpenVAS Manager installation enabled.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database is at revision 146.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager expects database at revision 146.
        OK: Database schema is up to date.
        OK: OpenVAS Manager database contains information about 45702 NVTs.
        OK: At least one user exists.
        OK: OpenVAS SCAP database found in /var/lib/openvas/scap-data/scap.db.
        OK: OpenVAS CERT database found in /var/lib/openvas/cert-data/cert.db.
        OK: xsltproc found.
Step 3: Checking user configuration ...
        WARNING: Your password policy is empty.
        SUGGEST: Edit the /etc/openvas/pwpolicy.conf file to set a password policy.
Step 4: Checking Greenbone Security Assistant (GSA) ...
        ERROR: No Greenbone Security Assistant (gsad) found.
        FIX: Please install Greenbone Security Assistant.
```

then i downloaded greenbone-security-assistant-6.0.9.tar.gz and done as mentioned in INSTALL file.
but when i run cmake it returns:

```
cmake ..
-- Configuring greenbone-security-assistant...
-- checking for module 'libopenvas_omp>=8.0.0'
--   package 'libopenvas_omp>=8.0.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:76 (pkg_check_modules)


-- checking for module 'libopenvas_base>=8.0.0'
--   package 'libopenvas_base>=8.0.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:77 (pkg_check_modules)


-- checking for module 'libopenvas_misc>=8.0.0'
--   package 'libopenvas_misc>=8.0.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:78 (pkg_check_modules)


-- Looking for libgcrypt...
-- Looking for libgcrypt... /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:111 (message):
  One or more required libraries was not found (see message above), please
  install the missing libraries and run cmake again.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

it seems cmake can not file any openvas lib.
all the openvas libs are located in default path:

```
/usr/lib/libopenvas_base.so.8
/usr/lib/libopenvas_base.so.8.0.6
/usr/lib/libopenvas_misc.so.8
/usr/lib/libopenvas_misc.so.8.0.6
/usr/lib/libopenvas_nasl.so.8
/usr/lib/libopenvas_nasl.so.8.0.6
/usr/lib/libopenvas_omp.so.8
/usr/lib/libopenvas_omp.so.8.0.6
```

this is mentioned in INSTALL file:

> If you have installed required libraries to a non-standard location,
>   remember to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to the
>   location of your pkg-config files before configuring:
>
> ```
> $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/your/location/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
> ```

but openvas installed it in default path and also i tried to set the environment var (PKG_CONFIG_PATH) as /usr/lib/ but not changed!

Comment: There should be corresponded `.pc` files under `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` directory, which is searched by `pkg-config`. Do you have these `.pc` files? (E.g., `libopenvas_omp.pc`).

Comment: i checked pkg-config 10 mins ago and i found exact what you said.
the /usr/lib/pkgconfig was empy and i did not have .pc file. so i download below link and extract .pc file from it. (ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/fedora-secondary/updates/23/ppc64/openvas-libraries-devel-8.0.5-1.fc23.ppc64.rpm)
it works, :)

Answer (score 0):

you may try  to reinstall gvm with another sources(like kali),and resetup.I have succeded to deal with this question by this way.